# Game in javascript/jquery: Change position of image when answering wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a math game in html and javascript and I want to change position of an image when giving the wrong answer in the game. So, when typing in the wrong answer to, for example, 9*6 the image is suppose to be moving towards a trap and eventually falling into the trap when reaching it. I have no idea how to do this but I've been using an if statement for when the answer is correct, so I need something to type in "else".

```
<img src="character.png" id="character" style="position:absolute; top:430px; left:330px">

<script>
var pp = document.getElementById("character");

function answers (event) {    
if...

else {   
pp.style.left = 350px; pp.style.top = 450px;  
}    
}  

</script>
```

Comment: Post what code you have tried.  You just need to use JS to update the position of the image in your `else` statement, but nobody is going to do your homework for you.

Comment: especially if we have to do it from scratch cause you didnt post any code

Comment: @dude - js is a pretty awesome language. If your implication is that js enables the user to manipulate it with console then also consider huge games like diable franchise being manipulated with just a text editor. If people want to ruin their experience they can. But js is a very capable language for games. Look into cocos2d-html5

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ animate of jquery might give you something to start with

Comment: @KaiQing The console thing was just an idea of something worse than js games. There are problems 1) JS is slow 2) It isn't designed for that, so you have to 3) do all kinds of weirdish things, like defining some div creator and styler function to create an object.

Comment: @Dude Yes, for good or bad javascript powered games are back. http://html5games.com/ At least today we have a standard of sorts http://www.ecmascript.org/ Instead of each browser having its own interrupation.

Comment: @dude - I think it depends on how you use it. I had to make some js games and they were at times sluggish and disappointing in general performance under certain circumstances. But no more so than everything else on the entire internet. Everyone gets pissed when a site loads slowly. So the answer is to not program the sites to require so much that they load slowly. Same really for games. It limits them, yeah, but places like zynga have managed to get quite far using js for games so it's got to be credible. Personally I prefer the safety of compiled languages for games but apple ruined that.

Comment: I think the best thing for games is iOS. Of course, if you want to have better support and such you will have to use the web. Mobile compatibility? Flash is out. JS is the only option. If I were then to chose between <canvas> and DOM, I would chose DOM. So, I guess it isn't _that_ bad, but I would prefer something else.

Comment: @Dude Wow. Welcome to the 2000's, it's not 1999 any more...

Comment: @meagar I know. Since it's the 2000s, people expect complex games with hard-to-render graphics. Of course, if you are doing something simple js will be easy. If you are doing something complicated js just won't cut it.

Comment: If you want to use jQuery, **use jQuery**. Replace your random calls to `document.getElementById("character");` with `$('#character')`.

Comment: @Dude You know that the [Unreal engine runs in-browser at full frame rate, in JavaScript, right?](http://www.unrealengine.com/html5/) Your understanding of JavaScript is *years* out of date. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BV32Cs_CMqo

Comment: @dude - cocos2d-html5 or cocos2d-javascript are ports of ios cocos2d engine. Well, as much as they can be as a runtime language, but the methods will be familiar if you know objective c

Comment: @meagar Another problem is js runs on _browsers_. Everyone know that browsers don't work. I got "This browser is currently unsupported. Please download Firefox 25 for an optimal experience or try anyway." on your link.

Comment: @KaiQing Native is always faster. JS may be "good enough" for most tasks, but defiantly not good for complex games.

Comment: @dude - nobody's arguing that. What's better is irrelevant if what's possible is not equivalent. Still though, many developers have shown that js is perfectly capable of making html5 games. Not all suck, so if you encounter a js game that does suck, blame the developer, not the language.

Comment: @Dude Yeeeaaahh, again, showing your knowledge of JS is way out of date. JS runs all over, and has for some time. And you know what runs on even fewer devices, if you want to make a game? iOS.

Comment: @Dude No, it's demonstrably good enough for complex games. I've just linked you to a demo of an Unreal-engine game running in browser. Code transcompiled to ASM.js performs close enough to natively that it's "good enough" for pretty much whatever you want to do.

Comment: I never said anything is impossible. You guys are arguing that it is possible, when I already agreed. @meagar I already told you about the compatibility problem. No, it didn't work in safari. It did work in Firefox tho, so I tested it. Nice graphics! It runs fast enough, I guess. Seems non-sluggish js is a cutting edge technology, since it isn't widely supported.

Answer (score 1):

these values

```
pp.style.left = 350px; 
pp.style.top = 450px;
```

need quotes

```
pp.style.left = "350px"; 
pp.style.top = "450px";
```

**Update**

if you need to use the style, (typeOf string), as a number you need to keep track of the numeric location with a global, (moveleft), the easiest way. Or use a function to extract the number from the string, ( normally reg expression http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp ), which is the harder way.

```
var pp = document.getElementById("character");
var moveleft = 0; /* typeOf number note I'm adding to this value before applying it. */ 
function answers (event) {    
    guess = document.getElementById("answer").value;    

    if( guess == rightanswer ){  
        $ ("#info").text(right);  
        $("#img").show();  
    }  else {  
        $ ("#info").text(wrong);  
        $("#img").hide();  
        moveleft += 350; 
        pp.style.left = moveleft + "px"; 
        pp.style.top = "450px";  
    }  
    new(event);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That made the image move once, but I want it to move everytime the answer is wrong, towards somthing. But this doesnt work:    
    pp.style.left = "+350px"; pp.style.top = "+450px";

Comment: You should also consider consistency. You are using jquery, so why not make use of it? `var pp = $('#character'); pp.css('left', '350px');` etc - better yet, `pp.animate({left: '350px'}, 500);`